# How to get index pattern configuration from elasticsearch / Kibana?

Tags: design-patterns, indexing, elasticsearch, export, kibana

Where are stored data about index patterns and scripted field? I need to automate import of index patterns and scripted fields. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Index patterns are kibana objects. They are stored in .kibana index in elasticsearch . You can automate import /export by reading the data stored in .kibana index on elasticsearch and reformatting the data according to your needs

Scripted fields can either be part of your dashboards/visualizations or the actual data contained in elastic. If a scripted field is part of your dashboard, you need to fetch it from the .kibana index. If it is part of your data in elastic, you need to fetch it using the Elastic API for the specific index